# ReferenceError - any is not defined (React Js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state, any

Getting error  **ReferenceError:
any is not defined** at line below -

`const [userInfos, setUserInfos] = useState < any > [];`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using TypeScript in a JavaScript project.

The correct code: `const [userInfos, setUserInfos] = useState([])`

Comment: Ohh. Actually I am following a video on youtube and he had written the code like this - "const [userInfos, setUserInfos] = useState < any > ([])" but I get error when i do it.

Comment: Because he is using TypeScript and you are not.

Comment: If this fixed it, mark this as the accepted answer please

Comment: So others who have your problem can see this fixed it, please mark it as the accepted answer with the checkmark (it's below the downvote button on my answer)

Comment: Your answer did help me and I do intend to mark it as an accepted answer but I still have to wait for 3 minutes.